# sql server query/subquery question

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a tables with data like this

```
Id  BookId  TagId
34  113421  9
35  113421  10
36  113421  11
37  113421  1
38  113422  9
39  113422  1
40  113422  12
```

I need to write a query (SQL Server) which gives me data according to the tags say if I want bookIds where 
tagid =9 it should return bookid 113421 and 113422  as it exists in both the books, but If I ask data for tags 9 and 10 it should return only book 113421 as that is the only book where both the tags are present.

Thanks

Parminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT
  BookId
FROM
  BookTags
WHERE
  TagId IN (9,10)
GROUP BY BookId HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

You need to set the `HAVING COUNT(*) = x` bit such that `x` is equal to the number of tags you're searching for (so in this case, it's 2. If you wanted 9, 10 & 11, you'd set it to 3, etc)

(Note: this is assuming you don't have books with duplicate duplicate TagId values)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Books WHERE TagId IN (9,10)

Comment: that wont help. it will give me rows from second set also.

Comment: That does not do what he wants. If you pass in 9 and 10, he only wants books with a TagId of 9 *and* 10. Your code would return all books with a TagId of 9 *or* 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct BookId From Books Where TagId = 9

intersect

Select distinct BookId From Books Where TagId = 10
```

Hope this helps